# Django rest framework - Nested queries, Passing queryset to response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using the Django rest framework and trying to fetch a response for a logistics use case that is based on two models.

Model 1 is basically a model that stores the data on which users are assigned which lanes(routes).

```
class BuyerFreightLaneMatrix(models.Model):
    buyer_email_id = models.ForeignKey(BuyerDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       related_name='buyer_Freight_Lane_matrix_buyer_detail_email_id_set')

    user_email_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="user_mapped_lanes")

    assigned_freight_lanes = models.ManyToManyField(MasterTableLane,
                                                 related_name='user_mapped_lanes')
```

and model 2 is where we store the data on the freight rates for each lane.

```
class FreightRate(models.Model):
    lane_name = models.ForeignKey(MasterTableLane, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                  related_name='Freight_rates_by_lane_name')
    lane_rate_per_ton = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                        related_name='freight_rates_created_by_User')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                        related_name='freight_rates_updated_by_User')
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated_at']
        get_latest_by = ['-updated_at']
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lane_name)+str('-Rs ')+str(self.lane_rate_per_ton)+ str('per MT')
```

My serializer is

```
class BuyerMappingWiseFreightRateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_mapped_lanes = BuyerFreightLaneMatrixSerializer(many=True,read_only =True)

    class Meta:
        model = BuyerFreightLaneMatrix
        fields = ['user_mapped_lanes']
        depth = 2
```

what I am trying to achieve is, for a given **user_email_id** in model 1, fetch the **assigned_freight_lanes** that are mapped to him, and then for each of those lanes, get the latest **lane_rate_per_ton** based on **updated_at** timestamp from model 2.

I have attempted to do this using Viewsets and generics in the Django rest framework and here are my views

```
class BuyerFreightRateView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BuyerMappingWiseFreightRateSerializer
    # queryset = BuyerFreightLaneMatrix.objects.all()
    # lookup_field = 'user_mapped_lanes'
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.user.id
        if len(BuyerFreightLaneMatrix.objects.filter(user_email_id=user_id)) >=1:
            FreightRateQuerySet = FreightRate.objects.filter(lane_name__user_mapped_lanes__user_email_id=user_id)
            print(FreightRateQuerySet.values())
            return FreightRateQuerySet.values('lane_name','lane_rate_per_ton')
```

and

```
class BuyerFreightRateView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = BuyerMappingWiseFreightRateSerializer
    queryset = FreightRate.objects.all()

    # lookup_field = 'user_mapped_lanes'
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.user.id

        if len(BuyerFreightLaneMatrix.objects.filter(user_email_id=user_id)) >=1:
            user_mapped_lanes = BuyerFreightLaneMatrix.objects.filter(user_email_id=user_id).values('assigned_freight_lanes')
            # print(user_mapped_lanes.values())
            # print(user_mapped_lanes[1])
            mapped_lanes = user_mapped_lanes
            # print("ML",mapped_lanes)
            for lane in enumerate(user_mapped_lanes):
                print(lane)
                lane_dict = lane[1]
                lane_id= lane_dict['assigned_freight_lanes']
                print(lane_id)
                latest_freight_rate = FreightRate.objects.filter(lane_name=lane_id)
                print(latest_freight_rate)
                return latest_freight_rate
            # mapped_lanes_queryset = FreightRate.objects.filter(lane_name__user_mapped_lanes__user_email_id=user_id)
            # # print(mapped_lanes_queryset)
            # # for lane in mapped_lanes_queryset:
            #     # print(lane)
            #
            # return mapped_lanes_queryset
```

I am getting a result like this in the console using the print statement

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 22, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('124.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 20, 9, 13, 766635, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 20, 9, 13, 766635, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 21, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('123.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 20, 8, 27, 346185, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 10, 20, 8, 27, 346185, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 20, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('5697.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 17, 43, 33, 913523, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 17, 43, 33, 913523, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 19, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('5648.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 17, 43, 26, 815163, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 17, 43, 26, 815163, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 18, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1254.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 17, 43, 5, 924835, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 17, 43, 5, 924835, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 17, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1504.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 42, 702115, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 42, 702115, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 16, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1948.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 37, 669825, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 37, 669825, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 15, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1924.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 31, 628940, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 31, 628940, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 14, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1578.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 26, 298696, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 26, 298696, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 13, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1546.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 21, 188828, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 40, 21, 189831, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 12, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1234.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 34, 25, 283600, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 34, 25, 283600, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 11, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1546.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 28, 21, 853032, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 15, 28, 21, 853032, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 10, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1478.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 14, 51, 20, 327069, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 14, 51, 20, 327069, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 9, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1254.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 14, 1, 50, 863803, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 14, 1, 50, 863803, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 8, 'lane_name_id': 1, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('123.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 14, 1, 15, 912433, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 14, 1, 15, 912433, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 7, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1276.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 7, 54, 57, 295224, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 7, 54, 57, 295224, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 6, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1246.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 7, 54, 46, 931781, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 7, 54, 46, 931781, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 5, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('1245.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 7, 54, 38, 861303, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 6, 7, 54, 38, 861303, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 4, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('85.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 12, 25, 35, 29142, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 12, 25, 35, 29142, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, {'id': 3, 'lane_name_id': 2, 'lane_rate_per_ton': Decimal('80.00'), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 12, 25, 24, 810786, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_by_user_id': 1, 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 12, 25, 24, 810786, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_by_user_id': 1}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
HTTP GET /cbo/api/buyerfreighttest 200 [0.08, 127.0.0.1:64397]
```

However, when I call the API in postman for testing, all I get is this

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

I am not sure if I am on the right path here. Which one is better suited for my use case, ViewSet or generic views? How do you make nested queries like this one and return a response accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 class BuyerFreightRateView(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = BuyerMappingWiseFreightRateSerializer
        # queryset = BuyerFreightLaneMatrix.objects.all()
        # lookup_field = 'user_mapped_lanes'
        def get_queryset(self):
              user_id = self.request.user.id
              if len(BuyerFreightLaneMatrix.objects.filter(user_email_id=user_id)) >=1:
                     FreightRateQuerySet = FreightRate.objects.filter(lane_name__user_mapped_lanes__user_email_id=user_id)
                     print(FreightRateQuerySet.values())
                     return FreightRateQuerySet.values('lane_name','lane_rate_per_ton')
        def get(self, request):
            buyer =  self.get_queryset()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(buyer,many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

You can take reference from this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    profile =  self.request.user.profile_set.get(id=self.request.user.id)

    return profile

     
    

def get(self, request):
    profile =  self.get_queryset()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(profile)
    #count = visitors.count() 
    profile_api = OrderedDict({'data':serializer.data})
    #visitor_api.update({'total':count})
    profile_api.update({'message':'Data Retrieved Sucessfully'})
    profile_api.update({'status':200})  
    return Response(profile_api)
```

Comment: Tried it, still getting the same result.

Comment: check print(serializer.data) What does it shows? in get function

Comment: It seems like your query_set is not getting return values

Comment: print(serializer.data) gives me ` [OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict(), OrderedDict()]`

Comment: I hope you specified Fields in serializer class

Comment: I think you might have to give class meta and fields in BuyerFreightLaneMatrix(models.Model)

Comment: I did that already. I made a few changes and now I am able to get this ``` [{"id":22},{"id":21},{"id":20},{"id":19},{"id":18},{"id":17},{"id":16},{"id":15},{"id":14},{"id":13},{"id":12},{"id":11},{"id":10},{"id":9},{"id":8},{"id":7},{"id":6},{"id":5},{"id":4},{"id":3},{"id":2},{"id":1}] ``` in the API output. only id  field is showing up.